# python-for-android androidmanifest.xml editing

Tags: android, python, buildozer

I've been working with kivy for android and I've had a few issues with linking new hardware permissions. At compile time it crashes, with no explaination even with logging = 2. Stranger yet, it crashes on an image built into the sdk (as in I didn't import, create, or include this. It's a default image that wouldn't otherwise cause a crash) and has no explaination, literally, as to why only that I should, as I stated before, enable logging level 2. Literally it just shows the red error text without an error. It doesn't do this without adding the permissions, which are for wifi enabling.
**I don't want assistance in writing the program, just direction as to where to find documentation for properly editing the AndroidManifest.xml specifically for buildozer.** I can find many tutorials for AndroidManifest.xml, but I fear most won't work for buildozer for the error I am having.

Note: I don't have the error available to me at this time, but I will link the log into this forum later today.

Comment: From top of my head I can recommend 'kivy crash course' playlist  on YouTube. There is one video about building for Android. Plus kivy 1.9.1 had an issue with building where portrait orientation was set in android.txt

Comment: @simplynail thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: This sounds like a possible [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - do you actually want to edit androidmanifest.xml, or do you want to add your extra permission? If the latter, it's probably easier to debug your problem with adding the wifi permission, in which case you should add your full log. If you really want to modify androidmanifest.xml manually you can find it somewhere in the .buildozer dir in your app directory, but it is copied/templated in multiple places so you must be careful to modify the right one and might get strange behaviour.

Comment: So which copy of 'AndroidManifest.xml' in the '.buildozer' sub-folders should I edit?